# How can I redirect to a file a system error from running an executable without a needed library?

Tags: bash, io

I am trying to put into a file an error that the system gives me.
I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="output.log"

echo "Starting" > $logfile

./cpi 2>&1 >> $logfile

echo "Ending" >> $logfile

exit
```

And the output I get in the file `output.log` is the following:

```
Starting
Ending
```

But in the screen I see this:

```
./cpi: error while loading shared libraries: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The error is on purpose. I took the path to that lib out of my #LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The point is, if the script runs in another machine and the library isn't there, I would like to get the error that goes to the screen.

I also need the output of my own program, thus I need the `2>&1 >> $logfile` after its execution.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding.

If you want both the standard output and standard error from `cpi` to go to `$logfile`, swap the order of the redirections:

```
./cpi >> $logfile 2>&1
```

Comment: It worked. Now I get the "no library" error in my `output.log` file.
I don't really understand why the position of this operator made the difference here. Would you care to explain further?
Thank you for the clean solution!

Comment: The bash man page explains it fairly well, but here's a brief explanation. The redirections are processed from left to right, so they way you had it would move standard error to standard output (which is still the terminal), then move standard output to a file. This way, you move standard output to the file, then move standard error to standard output (which is now the file).

Answer (score 0):

This error is reported by the loader and not the cpi binary so the redirection does not work here. You can test this by generating a cpi internal error. You might be able to log this error if you use a wrapper script to launch cpi.

Comment: The wrapper was my first idea of a solution, but I was looking for something simpler. And your rationale seems perfectly logical (for me) on the redirection not working since the error came from the loader. But chepner's solution worked! But I don't really understand why...